# Coping contents of folder across multiple data storages (hdd, external hdd)

Tags: software-recommendation, files, clipboard

I'm looking for some utility that will copy the contents of my working folder across multiple storages - hdd, external hdd, usb drives etc. I`m not looking for version control software (like cvs or svn), more like replication control on data changed in the folder.

Can you suggest something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unison is the tool I've heard most widely recommended to achieve this goal.  It is available as a package in the archives, and usually performs quite well.  Install with `apt-get install unison`.

In addition to file/folder synchronisation on a single host, unison can be configured to synchronise files between hosts (clients are available for a wide range of operating systems), which makes it very suitable for heterogenous environments.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one source, you should try `rsync`. It's really fast, works for local, networked and ssh files and is very customizable. Put it into a cronjob and you're set.

I use it for my backups at home. The only special thing I use is a rsync exclude file to omit i.e. browser cache files.

Answer (score 0):

I'll 2nd cweiske. I use rsync to copy all my files to my home directory on the machines I install various flavors of BSD and Linux on and vice versa.
I have it set up, similarly - ignore certain files, include file "x" in folder "y" but delete "z" (especially if doing a backup)